# SQL Server, how to merge two columns into one column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, calculated-columns

I have a SQL query

```
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA + TABLE_NAME AS ColumnZ 
FROM information_schema.tables
```

I want the result should be `table_Schema.table_name`.

help me please!!

Comment: Use `SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + TABLE_NAME` ....

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + TABLE_NAME AS ColumnZ 
FROM information_schema.tables
```

Comment: Thanks. Very simple '+' oprator compbine coumn in to single column

Answer (score 6):

This code work for you try this....

```
SELECT Title,
FirstName,
lastName, 
ISNULL(Title,'') + ' ' + ISNULL(FirstName,'') + ' ' + ISNULL(LastName,'') as FullName 
FROM Customer
```

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT CONCAT(TABLE_SCHEMA, '.', TABLE_NAME) AS ColumnZ FROM information_schema.tables
```

Comment: Watch out: `CONCAT` is a **new feature** in SQL Server **2012** and thus might not be available to the person asking

Comment: @marc_s I did not know this, it will be useful if I ever have to work with old MSSQL versions, thanks.

Comment: Being a new feature doesn't make the answer worthy of a downvote, in my opinion.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: just to be absolutely clear - it wasn't my downvote; I agree with you - it's a new feature, but it's correct - for that newer version of SQL Server. No downvote warranted ...

Answer (score 2):

From SQL Server 2017 onwards, there is `CONCAT_WS` operator, to concatenate with separators.

```sql
SELECT CONCAT_WS('.', TABLE_SCHEMA ,TABLE_NAME) AS ColumnZ 
FROM information_schema.tables
```

Comment: This is great for handling nulls, where you don't want the extra separators, and can do the same for empty strings in a column if it is wrapped in NULLIF().