# How to display 3 column value in a single rows

Tags: sql-server

I want to display 3 column values into single rows in SQL.

Input:

```
Branch |Phone1|Phone2|Phone3
abc    |12345 |456321|456321
```

Output:

```
Branch|Phone
abc   |12345,456321,45321
```

Please help

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25207771/sql-server-how-to-merge-two-columns-into-one-column

Comment: Simply try like `SELECT Branch, Phone1 + ',' + Phone2 +',' + Phone3 AS Phone FROM ....`

Comment: Please have a go and only post a question when stuck. We're not here to write your code for you.

Comment: I try to do this using variable and its done. but I have to create 3 variables and its not good that's why I need some alternative solution .so I simply post my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to leverage CONCAT function & CONCAT_WS function, as they handle NULL values: If there is a NULL value, it is replaced with empty string.

Different approaches are available to do concatenation

- CONCAT_WS (Available from SQL 2017). [CONCAT_WS on msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-ws-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

```sql
SELECT Branch, concat_ws(',',phone1, phone2, phone3) as phone
FROM
(
VALUES
('abc',12345,456321,456321)
) AS T(Branch,Phone1,Phone2,Phone3)
```

- Using CONCAT (Available from SQL Server 2012 onwards) [Read CONCAT on msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

```sql
SELECT Branch, concat(phone1,',', phone2,',', phone3) as phone
FROM
(
VALUES
('abc',12345,456321,456321)
) AS T(Branch,Phone1,Phone2,Phone3)
```

- Regular concatenation using concatenation operator `+`

```sql
SELECT Branch, cast(phone1 as varchar(10)) + ',' +  cast(phone2 as varchar(10)) + ',' +  cast(phone3 as varchar(10)) as phone
FROM
(
VALUES
('abc',12345,456321,456321)
) AS T(Branch,Phone1,Phone2,Phone3)
```

- If there is a possibility of NULL, have `ISNULL` clause to handle NULLs with empty string.

```sql
SELECT Branch, cast(ISNULL(phone1,'') as varchar(10)) + ',' +  cast(phone2 as varchar(10)) + ',' +  cast(phone3 as varchar(10)) as phone
FROM
(
VALUES
('abc',null,456321,456321)
) AS T(Branch,Phone1,Phone2,Phone3)
```

I would highly recommend `CONCAT_WS` option, as it makes the code simpler and handles NULLs easily.